# How to find out the color at specific coordinates in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

I have the following Code:

```
import numpy
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img=Image.open(r'C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\database\db1.jpg')
small_img=img.resize((16,16),Image.BILINEAR)
plt.imshow(small_img)
plt.show()
```

and it shows this image:
[image: image shown]

How can I find out if I have a black or a white Pixel at, for example x=6 y=6? (In the end I want to put it into a Numpy array with all the values)

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at `small_img`? Printed its value? Or `print(small_img[7][7])`? `small_img` is possibly already a numpy array, or very similar to it.

Answer (score 0):

PIL images have the `getpixel` function. Take a look here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pil-getpixel-method/

You can make like that:

```
small_img.getpixel((6, 6))
```